# Why is my url rewriting rule not working properly?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to write this redirection
**images/catalog/1002/10002/main-200x250.12345.jpg** to url **images/catalog/1002/10002/main.jpg?w=200&h=250&vw=main**

I tried this rule:

```
rewrite "^/images/(.*)/([a-z0-9]+)-([0-9])x([0-9]).([0-9]{5}).(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$" /images/$1/$2.$6?w=$3&h=$4&vw=$2 break;
```

It is not working, it return 404 not found error. I don't know what I'm missing.

Also when I remove double quotes (") I got this error

> directive "rewrite" is not terminated by ";"

And I don't clear see the utility of the sign **"** and when should I use it or avoid it

I m working on a Mac with MAMP Pro v 5.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add a quantifier for the width and height numbers in your regex. Try this (I added a twice a `+`, you might want to use `{X}` instead, where `X` is the amount of digits for each number (if it is always the same amount of digits)):

```
rewrite "^/images/(.*)/([a-z0-9]+)-([0-9]+)x([0-9]+).([0-9]{5}).(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$" /images/$1/$2.$6?w=$3&h=$4&vw=$2 break;
```

---

Your reqular expression needs to be quoted because there is a `}` in it.

I think the [nginx documentation about rewrite directive](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) will answer your question, when a regular expression needs to be quoted:

> If a regular expression includes the “}” or “;” characters, the whole
>   expressions should be enclosed in single or double quotes.